# Unable to determine error with this basic assembler program?

Tags: assembly, pic

I am new to assembler and have been given this simple program at university, but I cannot understand why it doesn't work. I can't really explain more, like I said, I pretty much started with this language this week.

```
list        p=16f690        ; list directive to define processor
        #include    <P16F690.inc>       ; processor specific variable definitions
        __CONFIG    _CP_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _BOR_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _WDT_OFF & _INTRC_OSC_NOCLKOUT & _MCLRE_ON & _FCMEN_OFF & _IESO_OFF


    main
        cblock  0x20
                num1,.250
        endc       
        org 0x00 ; Set code at program memory address 0x00
            goto init
        org 0x04 ; Put code at program memory address 0x04
            nop
            retfie
    count:
        movf num1,w
        addwf .150,w
    init:

        bcf STATUS, RP0
        bcf STATUS, RP1
        movlw 0xFF
        movwf PORTA
        bsf STATUS, RP0
        clrf TRISA
    run:

        nop
        goto run
        END                       ; directive 'end of program'
```

Comment: Are you seriously asking us to debug an assembly language program with no comments and not even a tag about what architecture it's for?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: In addition to @CarlNorum's comment, what do you mean by "doesn't work?"  In what way does it not work?

Comment: What is the program supposed to do?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are you getting assmebler errors?  What is the intended result?  Naked, uncommon assembler by itself isn't all that useful.  :)  BTW, for those following at home: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPASM_Quick_Ref_Card_30400g.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've taken a bit of pity on you:

Your `init` label sets a bunch of registers and fall thru into run, which nops in a really tight loop forever.  Fine.  The thing is, how is `count` supposed to be called?  Nothing references it and your initial `goto` skips over it.  It has no interrupt type return values around it so it can't be interrupt called.  Your code basically sets a few registers and does nothing forever.  Not very interesting.

I'm guessing you wanted it to count somehow, but you need to actually call it somehow.  Your choice on how to do it.